# how to convert the listview of winform to listview of wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listview

I am new to wpf. I have this code in my winform application and I want to have this code in wpf `ListView`.. But I don't know how to start..can someone there help to convert this in wpf `ListView` here is my code in winform

Below code show the value of the listed in item from the database..

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
      con = new SqlConnection(cs);
      string cd = "insert Into ProductSold(InvoiceNo,ProductID,Quantity,Price,TotalAmount) 
                        VALUES (@InvoiceNo,@ProductID,@Quantity,@Price,@Totalamount)";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(cd);
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("InvoiceNo", txtInvoiceNo.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductID", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TotalAmount", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
}
for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
      con = new SqlConnection(cs);
      con.Open();
      string cb1 = "update Product set QtyAvailable = QtyAvailable- " + ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text + " where ProductID= '" + ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "'";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(cb1);
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is simply not practical to convert Winforms code line by line to WPF. In WPF, your `ListView` object would be displaying data from some model object, and you would iterate on the model object, not the `ListView` itself (actually, even in Winforms, it's bad form to use the `ListView` as the actual container for the data...but it's more common to see that in Winforms than WPF). In any case, Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" site. You need to make some _effort_ yourself. If you have a specific problem after making the effort, then post a question about _that_.

Comment: Thanks Sir Peter, Do you have any reference where can I easily learn wpf + the MVVM. There are many tutorials, but some are more complicated. I want  one whic is more easy.

Comment: Unfortunately, WPF is itself complicated. Basic concepts are not very hard to learn, but to make full use of WPF will require effort on your part. One site I've found useful is http://wpf.2000things.com/. I'm not saying it's the best, but it does seem fairly comprehensive and the information is presented in "bite-sized" chunks. Having been through the WPF learning curve recently myself, I am sympathetic to your concerns, but I never found a "magic bullet". I simply struggled through, just as anyone would have to.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter. This is a big help for a beginner like me in wpf.

Comment: Good luck. For what it's worth, now that I know what I'm doing, I find WPF works very well for my purposes. I still run across the occasional annoyance now and then, but on the whole I prefer WPF over Winforms. One of the reasons it's harder to learn is that is has more features, and they don't always work or interact with each other in intuitive ways. But the features themselves are often useful and result in less/simpler user code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from [this link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/). In `WPF` you need set `ItemsSource` propery of your `ListView` and you can create one class for items. it can include your requirements (`ProductID, Quantity, Price, TotalAmount,...`) as some `Properies`. Then *there is not* `SubItem` in `WPF` unlike `WinForm`. You should create that class (for example `MyInvoiceClass`) and create a list of it's objects to use it as `ListView` Items.

You can look at this sample:

```
List<MyItemClass> items = new List<MyInvoiceClass>();
items.Add(new MyInvoiceClass() { InvoiceNo = "10", ProductID = 42, .... });
items.Add(new MyInvoiceClass() { InvoiceNo = "11", ProductID = 39, .... });
items.Add(new MyInvoiceClass() { InvoiceNo = "12", ProductID = 7, .... });

//Assign list of objects (Invoice List) to ItemsSource property
ListView1.ItemsSource = items;
```

Then you can use it like the following code and base on the loop in your question

```
foreach (MyInvoiceClass invoice in ListView1.ItemsSource)
{
    // NOW use the "invoice" object to access its properties
}
```

Please consider [@PeterDuniho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho) points, in the first comment on your question, good luck..

Comment: Yes.. I consider the point of Sir Peter, Thanks Sir Ram, for the sample. It helps to have an idea on how will i gonna code this list in wpf. Thanks again Sir Ram.